# Can we listen to changes in csv file in a supabase table?

Tags: csv, supabase, supabase-database

Having a CSV file, after importing it to the Supabase Database, how can we listen to the changes in the same CSV file?

Is uploading the CSV file in the Storage and then writing a Hook Function to check if the CSV file is updated a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import data via CSV via the following option.
[image]

You can also listen to changes in the table at your client as per their documentation. [Flutter Documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/stream) [Postgress Changes](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime/postgres-changes). Make sure the table you are listening to is in the public schema.

You can write an automation script at your server to sync with CSV and stream, using postgress copy command.[SQL Copy](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)